# How to make fixed menu bar so that it doesn't move when resizing the browser window

Tags: html, css

I would like to make my menu bar have a fixed positioning so that when the browser window is resized, the menu doesn't move. I also would it to work for all browsers. I have done a bit of answer browsing however the solutions i have seen doesn't seem to work for me.

Here's my code:

**CSS**

```
#nav ul {
    padding:0px;
    height:37px;
    position: fixed;
    top: -12px;
    left: 850px;
}

.nav li {
    margin:0px;
    list-style: none;
}

#nav li, #nav .last {
    float:left;
}

#nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    width:auto;
    font-weight:bold;
    height:auto;
    padding: 85px 10px 5px;
    height:18px;
    color:#3a434e;
    font-size:12px;
    float:left;
}

#ie7 #nav a, #ie6 #nav a {
    font-size:9px;
    padding:11px 8px 5px;
}

#nav li:hover a, #nav .active a {
    color:#4D4D4D!important;
    background-image:url(../imgs/nav_active.gif);
    background-position:right center;

    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

#nav li:hover a {
    color:#FFF!important;
    background-color: #C1272D;  
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="nav" class="nav">
    <ul>            
        <li class="active normal"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="normal"><a href="#">Basket</a></li>
        <li class="normal"><a href="#">Lightbox</a></li>
        <li class="normal"><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
        <li class="normal"><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        <li class="normal"><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#">Logout</a></li>        
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide your `html` code

Comment: I have added the HTML however, i am not supposed to modify the HTML code. Only the CSS as i have been told by my manager

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/9WkMr/?

Comment: Yes however i would like it to be a horizontal bar as opposed to a vertical menu bar.

Comment: It should be easy with `position:fixed` and `width:400px`. What specific problem are you having?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9WkMr/1/

Comment: The horizontal menu bar should be positioned top right corner and when i make my browser window wider, the menu bar doesn't move but then load's of white space is created to the right hand side. I would it so that when the window is resized, the menu bar is fixed to the same width of the browser window if that makes sense?

Comment: @Morpheus how would i make this go to the right of the screen instead of the left? i tried setting left to right instead but it had no effect

Comment: It should be as simple as `right: 0` or remove `width` property from `ul`

Answer (score 0):

Either set a width in a percentage that will be based off the viewport width. Or set both right and left values.

```
   left: distance from left;
   right: distance from right;
```

Comment: I have tried adding a width in percentage but my menu bar just disappears